# Problemas com impressão de php com file_get_contents(); - mpdf

Tags: php, mpdf

Estou utilizando o mpdf para gerar um relatório, e para isto estou chamando outro arquivo `.php` que possui as informações, através do `file_get_contents();`.

Está exibindo o conteúdo desse arquivo, somente não lê o php corretamente, como exemplo o código: `<?php echo 'Olá'; ?>`, simplesmente aparece tudo, ao invés de aparecer somente o Olá.

Alguém poderia me ajudar?

Comment: Poste o código que está usando, para que possamos ajudar.

Comment: Respondi, mas tenho uma pequena impressão que a pergunta é duplicada.

Comment: @AndréBaill acho que nem precisa de código.

Answer (score 1):

`file_get_contents` não interpreta o código PHP. Ele apenas lê um arquivo como string e armazena na memória.

Para que o código php seja interpretado e você possa ver o que foi impresso pelo `echo` deve utilizar a função `include/require`.

O `include` executará imediatamente o `echo`, sendo o mesmo impresso na saída do navegador, e não no PDF.

Para resolver esse problema, provavelmente você terá que capturar o buffer e saída, assim:

```
ob_start();

include 'php_que_quero_incluir.php';

$saida = ob_get_clean();
```

Comment: Dá para usar para `file_get_contents()` para executar uma url, ela é processada e o resultado armazenado em uma variável. Se tivesse o código da pergunta ficaria mais fácil :P.

Comment: Faz sentido @rray, mas pela descrição dele eu já detectei qual era o erro.